# CSS :hover affect element before the element pointed

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="option"></a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible, using CSS, change the backgroung position of "option" when the mouse is over "submenu"?

I saw the [CSS Referente](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and i tried to use ">", "+" and "~", but it doesn't work. I don't know if i am using incorrectly or if it isn't possible.

Can anybody help me please?

**EDIT 1**

Here is the CSS that isn't working:

```
a.option~ul.submenu:hover {
    background-position:0 -48px;
}
```

According [CSS Referente](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), in my case, the "~" selects every "ul" element that are preceded by a "a" element, but isn't working for my code.

Comment: Can we see your CSS? also avoid w3schools. there are much better resources out there. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_Reference

Comment: it would work out if you make "option" a child of "submenu"

Comment: @rlemon: The sin here is not just linking to W3Schools, but linking to W3Schools **and** tagging the question [w3c]...

Comment: @rlemon Please see the EDIT 1

Comment: You read the table wrongly; in there it says `p~ul` selects `ul` that is preceded by `p`. It does not select `p` that precedes or is preceded by `ul`!

Comment: "By the CSS Referente, the "~" selects every element that are preceded by a element, but in my case, isn't working." because in your case you want to select the preceding element, this is selecting elements which are preceded by an element. so it is selecting the .submenu

Comment: @rlemon, RyanWheale said the following in a answer below: "In plain english this reads: When hovering over .submenu, change the background position of the .option which comes immediately AFTER .submenu". I think the problem is because "option" is before "submenu", if i could change the order, maybe it would be resolved.

Comment: See [How to affect other elements when a DIV is hovered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get close to what you are wanting with your html structure is to put a `:hover` on the `li`. Something like:

```
.container > li:hover > .option {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tXEhy/2/) which doesn't change `background-position`, but `color`. When hovering over `.submenu` there will also be a hover on the parent `li`.

Comment: It works! Thanks! I've removed only the first ">", so the declaration is this: .container li:hover > .option

Answer (score 4):

If you could put the "option" AFTER the UL, then it will work:

```
<ul class="container">
    <li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
         </ul>
        <a href="#" class="option"></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
.submenu:hover + .option {
    background-position: -20px -20px;
}
```

In plain english this reads: When hovering over .submenu, change the background position of the .option which comes immediately AFTER .submenu.  Hope that helps.

```
.submenu:hover ~ .option {
    background-position: -20px -20px;
}
```

This is the same thing as the "+" selector, except the .option does not have to come *immediately* behind the .submenu.  For example, the "+" **won't** work for the following markup, but the "~" **will** work.

```
<ul class="container">
    <li>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span>Some other element</span>
        <a href="#" class="option"></a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very clear your explanation, thanks. The problem is that a i can't put "option" after "submenu", i would have many changes in my HTML/CSS structure. Maybe i will try implement the @ScottS suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using css since .option is not a child of submenu